# Question about distributed database system

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, distributed

I am currently creating a site(php,css,html,ajax,MySql) which will have heavy user usage of space(regarding data). These data are quite essential and the can NOT be lost, it is really essential.

I am looking for tips on servers, languages and everything else(even theory) about distributed database systems. Any help would be really appreciated. Also it would be great if the system used mysql.

Thank you

P.S. dont link Google.com. I have done that and reached nothing but a wall :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're Googling for the wrong terms. If you searched for `MySql Replication` you might run into [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Database replication is what enables a "distributed database system". You should also look into [clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) to see if that type of distributio/replicationn might meet your needs.

Also, you didn't specify if you were running LAMP or WAMP but here's a how-to on setting up a [MySQL and Apache cluster](http://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian).

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but thank you about the links :)

Comment: I think Peter is looking for a sharding Mysql table, i.e. single table across mutiple servers.